# R: Tabulate Items Within a List

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

See below for a few calls demonstrating what I am working with. The result of the 3rd and 4th call, that single number, is the only statistic I care about in this larger list, `inclusiveEffects`. It is from a `summary(lm(. . .))[[4]]` function iterated across twenty subjects (so twenty big blocks in `inclusiveEffects`, with only one shown, and twenty (Intercept)~Estimate values hopefully pulled off/out of those blocks), and I'd like to have a nice little table with no extra garbage.

Second question ever; open to formatting/style/usage/code-insetting feedback & other criticism. Thanks for supporting entry into the R community.

```
> inclusiveEffects[1]
$`1`
         Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2.5333333  0.9784990 2.5889994 0.06074795
time        0.2285714  0.2512554 0.9097177 0.41443008

> inclusiveEffects[[1]]
             Estimate Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 2.5333333  0.9784990 2.5889994 0.06074795
time        0.2285714  0.2512554 0.9097177 0.41443008
> inclusiveEffects[[1]][1]
[1] 2.533333
> inclusiveEffects[[1]][2]
[1] 0.2285714
```

Comment: Something like `sapply(inclusiveEffects, function(x) x[[1]][2] )` maybe, but it's a bit hard to know for sure without exact example data.

Comment: I think you are misconstruing my question, which is my fault.
$`1` is the basic item. There are twenty of them -- up to $`20`. Here is another:
    > inclusiveEffects[14]
    $`14`
                 Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept) 1.3333333  1.4436506 0.9235845 0.4079732
    time        0.4285714  0.3706952 1.1561287 0.3119786

sapply(inclusiveEffects, function(x) x[[1]][2]) returns

Comment: `sapply(inclusiveEffects, function(x) x[1] )` then probably if each one is an output of a matrix of results from the `summary()` object. Or even `sapply(inclusiveEffects, \`[\`, 1)` for that matter,

Comment: They worked, impressive! Thank you.